# Properties option doesn't show in SSMS for Azure DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms, ssms-2017

I am trying to create a full-text search mechanism, to do that I created full text catalog in my local database. Then I opened context menu and it had properties option.
[image: local db]

I opened it and set up tables/views tracking. But when I tried to do the same with remote Azure database, I could not open properties window.
[image: remote db]

Any idea how can I open/edit settings I need?

Comment: My suggestion is to install the newest [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I literally donwloaded the newest few hours ago

Comment: All you need to do with full-text search on Azure SQL Database is better if you do it with Transact-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was playing around with SSMS and found an interesting solution to this. As Alberto Morillo mentioned, to do operations with Azure SQL DB you need to use Transact-SQL. I never worked with it and basic SQL knowledge turned out to be not enough. But I found interesting option in SSMS. I went to my local DB, created new catalog, set everything like I need and instead of saving, I pressed 'Save script to file'. This generated Transact-SQL code that I needed, all I did after is changed names and executed that queries on my Azure DB.